# Wordpress - Updating page and hit submit - stops at post.php but page is still updated

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have several pages that I am updating in Wordpress. When I hit "Update" the page starts to load, but then stops at `/wp-admin/post.php`. However, the page does get updated. Nothing has changed on the site, and this was working fine just a few hours ago, but is now seemingly problematic on any page I update.

As I said, the updates are going through, page preview works fine, but when I hit update, then it just stops at `/wp-admin/post.php` and I have to go back or find the page again to make edits.

This was working fine this morning, and now it does it on every page. I have cleared the cache several times, but again, this just started to happen.

Thanks for any insight that could be provided.

Comment: check browser console to see any error.

Comment: No errors in the console. Just shows post.php 200 ok - thats it

Comment: then it may be because of any autoupdate plugin or theme. update the wordpress and check. Before updating, take the backup of your files and database

Comment: Nope that is not the cause either... could be our terrible service provider by the name of Godaddy... they are always breaking things..

Comment: :) yes they are

Comment: Seems to be only on these certain pages, as I just moved on to other pages, and those are working fine. The pages that are giving me have flash embed codes in them, so maybe that is the issue

Comment: might be a case